# How to scale environment map perspective according to the position of the main camera

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have an environment map that I apply to a cube. When I am close to the cube (near where the face of the cube map is rendered from) the perspective appears correctly. but as I move away The reflection does not scale down.

Close
[image: Close]

Far
[image: Far]

As you can see, the pillar being reflected in the cube does not scale down as I move away, it remains the same size.

How can I get the reflection to scale according to the distance from the main camera?

Comment: This is a parallax issue. Read [Image-based Lighting approaches and parallax-corrected cubemap](https://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/image-based-lighting-approaches-and-parallax-corrected-cubemap/)

Comment: Thank you. The section "Parallax correction for local cubemaps" is what I needed.